# Bigcommerce Coupon creation redeem per customer not working

Tags: bigcommerce

I am trying to create a coupon code with the following customer uses settings.

1. code can be used by unlimited number of customers. setting it to 0.
2. max uses per customer is set to 1.

With this settings first customer who is applying the code can redeem it fine but other customers always sees code is expired though expiry is set to one year later.

how can i make this type of coupon code working in bigcommerce?

Comment: Are you doing any of the testing yourself and seeing that you can't redeem it? I tested it in my own store and had no issues using the same settings.

Comment: So you are creating the coupon via the API.... please share your full request as well as the response you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to **Marketing › Coupon Codes**. Your existing and sample coupon codes will be displayed.
2. Click **Create a coupon code**.
3. Fill out the coupon code details:

**Coupon code -** the code entered at checkout e.g. FREESHIPPING

**Coupon name -** the name of the coupon (for reference) e.g. Free Shipping over $50

**Discount type -** choose from the options provided

Dollar amount off the order total

Dollar amount off each item in the order

Percentage off each item in the order

Dollar amount off the shipping total

Free shipping

**Discount Amount -** the percentage or dollar amount to take off (for all discount types except free shipping)

**Minimum Purhcase optional -** the minimum amount a customer must spend in one order to be able to apply the coupon

**Number of uses -** use this to limit how many types the coupon can be used

Limit total number of uses limits how many times a coupon can be used at all in your store

Limit number of uses per customer limits how many times a single customer (based on email address) can use the coupon

**Enabled -** check this for the coupon code to work in your store. Uncheck to keep the coupon settings saved but not enable it.

**Expiry Date optional -** after this date, the coupon will be disabled automatically

4. Select which categories or products to limit your coupon to. If you do not want to limit it, select All Categories from the category list.

**Limit to specific categories -** select This coupon code can be used with these categories

**Limit to specific products -** select This coupon code can be used with these products, then click Add a Product and navigate to your products

5. Choose any advanced settings if desired, then save your changes.